# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, console-application, asp-net-config-builders

I was trying to create user secrets in application console in c# in last days but I wasn't able to generate the file secret .

I ended up  followed  [this tutoriel](https://medium.com/@hammadarif/how-to-safely-manage-passwords-in-net-applications-a546a481c41c) and finally was able to create secret.xml . But when I tried to read data from the secret.xml file, it gave me this error :

```
Thrown exception: 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' in System.Configuration.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll
An error occurred while loading a configuration file: Unable to load the file or assembly 'Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.UserSecrets, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral' or one of its dependencies. The specified file can not be found.
```

At the beginning I was able to read the password data from the config file , but when I tried to read it from secret file it seemsnot woriking .

**Solution tried :**
-removed the reference to  UserSecrets then added it again using Nuget .

Here is my code : [click here](https://github.com/pilomilokilo/test_secrets)

**App.config :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false"/>
    </configSections>
    <configBuilders>
        <builders>
          <add name="Secrets" userSecretsFile="c:\\secrets\\secret.xml" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.UserSecretsConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.UserSecrets, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>
        </builders>
      </configBuilders>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
    </startup>
  <appSettings configBuilders="Secrets">
    <add key="password" value="This is a password placeholder"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**Program.cs :**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
            Console.WriteLine($"Password is {password}");
        }
```

Comment: Try run the VS as admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my test, I find the solution. You can try change the current .net framework

version to 4.7.1 or later.

Click properties-> choose target framework-> choose .net Framework 4.7.2

like the following:

[image]

Then, you can refer to the app.config I test.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false"/>
    </configSections>
    <configBuilders>
        <builders>
        <add name="Secrets" userSecretsFile="D:\\secrets.xml" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.UserSecretsConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.UserSecrets, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/></builders>
    </configBuilders>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2"/>
    </startup>
  <appSettings configBuilders="Secrets">
    <add key="password" value="This is a password placeholder"/>
  </appSettings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Base" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

You can know .net framework has been changed to v4.7.2.

Finally, I can get the correct result from the console app.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your help I appreciate it .I followed the steps you provided , 1-searched for the publicKeyToken of the ConfigurationBuilder.Base assembly and the chaged the newVersion since mine is 1.0.0.0 ,but then it throws me this error :`Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.UserSecrets, Version = 2.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The definition found in the assembly manifest does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

Comment: I would love if you could give a hand of help how I can solve it . Thank u very much in advance ^^